# Elasticsearch query to filter documents where value1 == value2 with Go olivere/elastic

Tags: go, elasticsearch

I need to build query to get documents where doc.value1 == doc.value2

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool" : {
            "filter" : [{
                "script" : {
                    "script" : {
                        "source": "doc['val1'].value == doc['val2'].value",
                        "lang": "painless"
                     }
                }
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

This what I need to build with olivere/elastic, it work if I send it as POST request.

In golang I have something like

```golang
"github.com/olivere/elastic"
...

query := elastic.NewBoolQuery()
// then add something to this query or leave it empty it works fine
// but if I add 
query = query.Filter(elastic.NewBoolQuery().Must(elastic.NewScript("doc.['val1'].value == doc.['val2'].value")))
// I'm getting: Error 400 (Bad Request): [source] query malformed,
// no start_object after query name [type=parsing_exception]

// Then i run it like:
client, err := elastic.NewClient()
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
    return
}
resp, err := client.Search("myIndex").Type("myDoc").Query(query).TrackTotalHits(true).Size(limit).Do(context.Background())
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
```

Comment: Can you show the error you see in the ES server logs, please?

Comment: Can you try `query = query.Filter(NewScriptQuery(NewScript("doc.['val1'].value == doc.['val2'].value1")))`?

Comment: Val, i would if i knew how to do this)
Andrei, i guess it make me closer to solution, but now with `query = query.Filter(elastic.NewScriptQuery(elastic.NewScript("doc.['val1'].value == doc.['val2'].value")))` new error is: Error 400 (Bad Request): all shards failed [type=search_phase_execution_exception]

Comment: You'd have to share more from that exception, ideally the stacktrace from Elasticsearch, as @Val mentioned.

Comment: The ES server logs are located in the `logs` folder if you installed from a ZIP or tarball or in `var/log/elasticsearch` if you installed from an RPM/DEB.

Comment: Update: now i just failed with dot after `doc.['val']`

`query = query.Filter(elastic.NewScriptQuery(elastic.NewScript("doc['val1'].value == doc['val2'].value")))` - works, thanks all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
query = query.Filter(elastic.NewScriptQuery(elastic.NewScript("doc['val1'].value == doc['val2'].value")))
```